# How to test a react component that should disappear after an animation is executed?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have created a pop-up template component that gets closed after a "submerge" animation is executed

```js
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import type React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { CloseIcon } from 'Components/Icons';

type Props = {
  isOpen: boolean;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  onClose: () => void;
};

export const PopUpTemplate = ({ isOpen, children, onClose }: Props) => {
  const [isClosing, setIsClosing] = useState(false);

  const startClosing = useCallback(() => {
    setIsClosing(true);
  }, [setIsClosing]);

  const handleAnimationEnd: React.AnimationEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> = useCallback(
    ({ animationName }) => {
      if (animationName === 'submerge-animation') {
        setIsClosing(false);
        onClose();
      }
    },
    [setIsClosing, onClose]
  );

  if (!isOpen && !isClosing) return null;

  return (
    <div
      data-testid="pop-up-overlay"
      onClick={startClosing}
      className="..."
    >
      <div
        data-testid="pop-up-modal"
        onAnimationEnd={handleAnimationEnd}
        onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
        className={classNames(
          'emerge ...',
          {
            submerge: isClosing,
          }
        )}
      >
        {children}
        <button
          data-testid="pop-up-close-button"
          onClick={startClosing}
          className="..."
        >
          <CloseIcon />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

These are the animations:

```scss
.emerge {
    animation: emerge-animation .3s ease-in-out forwards;
}
    
.submerge {
    animation: submerge-animation .3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes emerge-animation {
    from {
        transform: translateY(200%);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@keyframes submerge-animation {
    from {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(200%);
    }
}
```

I wrote the following test to check that it closes when the user clicks the close icon

```js
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { usePopUp } from 'Hooks';
import { PopUpTemplate } from 'Components/PopUpTemplate';

const PopUp = () => {
  const [isOpen, open, close] = usePopUp();
  return (
    <>
      <button data-testid="pop-up-open" onClick={open}></button>
      <PopUpTemplate isOpen={isOpen} onClose={close}>
        <div data-testid="tc-title">Title</div>
      </PopUpTemplate>
    </>
  );
};

describe('Pop-Up', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(<PopUp />);
  });

  it('should close the pop-up when clicking the close icon', () => {
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('pop-up-open'));
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('pop-up-overlay')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('pop-up-modal')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('pop-up-close-button')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('tc-title')).toBeInTheDocument();

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('pop-up-close-button'));
    fireEvent.animationEnd(screen.getByTestId('pop-up-modal'));

    expect(screen.queryByTestId('pop-up-overlay')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('pop-up-modal')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('tc-title')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

The implementation of the `usePopUp` hook is really simple

```js
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useToggle } from 'usehooks-ts';

export const usePopUp = (): [boolean, () => void, () => void] => {
  const [isOpen, , setIsOpen] = useToggle(false);
  const openPopUp = useCallback(() => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }, [setIsOpen]);
  const closePopUp = useCallback(() => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  }, [setIsOpen]);

  return [isOpen, openPopUp, closePopUp];
```

But I get the following error

```bash
 FAIL
  Pop-Up
    ✕ should close the pop-up when clicking the close icon (54 ms)

  ● Pop-Up › should close the pop-up when clicking the close icon

    expect(element).not.toBeInTheDocument()

    expected document not to contain element, found <div... instead

      30 |     fireEvent.animationEnd(screen.getByTestId('pop-up-modal'));
      31 |
    > 32 |     expect(screen.queryByTestId('pop-up-overlay')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
         |                                                        ^
      33 |     expect(screen.queryByTestId('pop-up-modal')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
      34 |     expect(screen.queryByTestId('tc-title')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
      35 |   });
```

Comment: If you solved this, please let me know how :) But the problem is that `animationName` you are checking in even handler is `undefined` in test (so your state setters are not executing). I couldn't find a way to actually set the name when firing event. I worked around it by not checking animation name in tests, but I don't really like this "solution"...